# R: arranging and sorting within nested list

Tags: r, list, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which has a column of list type that contains four numbers:

```
          Size
Ford   1,2,3,4
Gm     2,3,5,6
Nissan 2,3,4,5
Toyota 1,2,2,4
```

here car names (Ford etc) are row names and Size ("1,2,3,4" etc) is a column of lists.

I would like to sort this data frame by the 3rd number in column Size so we get the following result:

```
          Size
Toyota 1,2,2,4
Ford   1,2,3,4
Nissan 2,3,4,5
Gm     2,3,5,6
```

In a complete example I have many columns in each row but I still want to do sorting by the 3rd value in Size column.

Comment: When asking about a non-standard structure, it's probably worth using `dput` to create a reproducible example. e.g. `data.frame(Size=I(list(1:4,c(2,3,5,6),2:5,c(1,2,2,4))),row.names=c("Ford","Gm","Nissan","Toyota"))`

Comment: sorry, not that good yet to be able to create reproducible example easily, but your solutions work perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Something like below will work - I'll remake the data first:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ID=1:4,
  Size=I(list(1:4,c(2,3,5,6),2:5,c(1,2,2,4))),
  row.names=c("Ford","Gm","Nissan","Toyota")
)
```

Which looks like:

```
       ID       Size
Ford    1 1, 2, 3, 4
Gm      2 2, 3, 5, 6
Nissan  3 2, 3, 4, 5
Toyota  4 1, 2, 2, 4
```

Then order it:

```
dat[order(sapply(dat$Size,"[",3)),]

       ID       Size
Toyota  4 1, 2, 2, 4
Ford    1 1, 2, 3, 4
Nissan  3 2, 3, 4, 5
Gm      2 2, 3, 5, 6
```

Comment: I had the same `order`/`sapply` solution but without the ID column, the dataframe seemed to convert to a list when you tried to order it. Any insight on why this happens?

Comment: @Marius - You can stop that happening with `dat[order(sapply(dat$Size,"[",3)),,drop=FALSE]` - see the help file at `?"["` - "*If (drop==) ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples)*"

Comment: this solution works well for me, data.frame is preserved even without ID, perhaps because I originally have more than one column. Thank you!

Comment: @Sergey - yep, it is preserved because with multiple columns there is no simpler form for it to be coerced to.